# Is there a way to simplify this following mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I came up with the following query to return product pricing data. This query works fine, although I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify/optimize it?

The query pulls info about the product and pricing details for each product. If there is no pricing details (p_p.`pl_id` = 2) for particular product join another query with pricing details (p_p.`pl_id` = 1). Finally group all products by id to get distinct rows.

Tables used:
**products** - some details about the products like name, description etc.
**product_pricing (p_p)** - contains pricing details for every product. There may be more that one records for one product because product price varies depending on ordered quantity

```
SELECT * FROM (
(
SELECT `products`.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(p_p.`qty_range` SEPARATOR '|') AS qty_range, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(p_p.`p_price` AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '|') AS price 
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `prod_pricing` AS p_p ON p_p.`prod_id` = `products`.`prod_id` 
WHERE `products`.`account_id` = 2
AND p_p.`pl_id` = 2
GROUP BY `products`.`prod_id`
) 
UNION
(
SELECT `products`.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(p_p.`qty_range` SEPARATOR '|') AS qty_range, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(p_p.`p_price` AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '|') AS price 
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `prod_pricing` AS p_p ON p_p.`prod_id` = `products`.`prod_id` 
WHERE `products`.`account_id` = 2
AND p_p.`pl_id` = 1
GROUP BY `products`.`prod_id`
)) AS list
GROUP BY list.`prod_id`
```

Comment: use a stored proc (assuming your on the right Mysql version)?

Comment: You don't get distinct records because of joining to PROD_PRICING.  Looks like you want pl_id 2, or 1 if there's no 2 records for a product...

Comment: OMG Ponies: Because I group temp table 'list' by 'prod_id' I get distinct records but I know that this is not a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.
I created two temporary tables t1,t2 that reflect data with pl_id = 1 and 2. Next I joined those tables to the products table and with IF condition returned products with pricing from pl_id = 2 and pl_id =1 only when pricing for pl_id = 2 doesn't exist.
Thanks to everyone for help!

Here's the query

```
SELECT p.*,
IF(t2.pl_id IS NULL,t1.qty_range,t2.qty_range) AS qty_range,
IF(t2.pl_id IS NULL,t1.price,t2.price) AS price
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT p_p.prod_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p_p.qty_range SEPARATOR '|') AS qty_range, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(p_p.p_price AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '|') AS price 
    FROM prod_pricing AS p_p WHERE p_p.pl_id = 1
    GROUP BY p_p.prod_id
) AS t1 ON t1.prod_id = p.prod_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT p_p.prod_id,p_p.pl_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p_p.qty_range SEPARATOR '|') AS qty_range, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(p_p.p_price AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '|') AS price 
    FROM prod_pricing AS p_p WHERE p_p.pl_id = 1
    GROUP BY p_p.prod_id
) AS t2 ON t2.prod_id = p.prod_id 
WHERE p.account_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited: I think I got what you mean now, try:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2,  --[more columns from products table]
IF (t.price2 IS NULL, t.price1, t.price2) AS price,
IF (t.price2 IS NULL, t.qty_range1, t.qty_range2) AS qty_range
FROM
    (
    SELECT p.col1, p.col2 , --[more columns from products table]
    GROUP_CONCAT(p_p1.qty_range SEPARATOR '|') AS qty_range1, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(p_p1.p_price AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '|') AS price1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p_p2.qty_range SEPARATOR '|') AS qty_range2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(p_p2.p_price AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '|') AS price2 
    FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN prod_pricing AS p_p1 ON p_p1.prod_id = p.prod_id AND p_p1.pl_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN prod_pricing AS p_p2 ON p_p2.prod_id = p.prod_id AND p_p2.`pl_id` = 2
    GROUP BY p.prod_id) AS t
Having price IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I tried that already. This query will get pricing details for both pl.id = "1" and "2". What I want to get is, if there is no product pricing for pl.id = 2 then get pricing for pl.id = 1

Comment: This query makes a lot of sense but there is still something missing. For products that have pricing for both pl_id =1 and 2 I get combined pricing instead of getting only pricing for pl_id = 2

Comment: @marcin_koss: Are you sure? In case there are matches for both joins, the temp table (t) will have data in columns price1, price2, qty_range1 and qty_range2 - but the final result should have only the data from price 2 because of `IF (t.price2 IS NULL, t.price1, t.price2) AS price` and the data from qty_range2 because of `IF (t.price2 IS NULL, t.qty_range1, t.qty_range2) AS qty_range`

Answer (score 0):

As the two UNIONS are nearly identical, perhaps you could look into [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

You could have

```
WHERE `products`.`account_id` = 2
AND `products`.`prod_id`
AND CASE x
    WHEN y THEN
      p_p.`pl_id` = 2
    ELSE
      p_p.`pl_id` = 1
```

Though it's not clear where/how you determine if there is pricing detail.  But whatever column determines that would go in for  the **x** and it's value in the **y**.

Comment: The CASE condition could be a SELECT statement if need be.

Comment: SELECT `products` .  * , 
GROUP_CONCAT( p_p.`qty_range` SEPARATOR '|' ) AS qty_range, 
GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( p_p.`p_price` AS CHAR ) SEPARATOR '|' ) AS price
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `prod_pricing` AS p_p ON p_p.`prod_id` = `products`.`prod_id`
WHERE `products`.`account_id` =2
AND CASE p.p`p_product_id` 
WHEN '' 
THEN
      p_p.`pl_id` = 2
    ELSE
      p_p.`pl_id` = 1 - I tried this query but I'm getting errors.